# block UI is not working in IE 8

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am trying to block the UI while a div is displayed on the page. TO block the UI I have made a div in form like that:(This is not the div which i display, It is used to implement css)

```
  <t:div id="fadebackgroundstyle1" style="display:none;text-align:center;">
</t:div>
```

and css for this is follows:

```
       #fadebackgroundstyle1 {
display: none;
position: fixed;
top: 0%;
left: 0%;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: url(../images/overlay.png) repeat scroll 19px center
    transparent;
z-index: 1001;
-moz-opacity: 0.8;
opacity: .80;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80)";
filter: alpha(opacity = 80);
  }
```

onclick of div i call:

```
        document.getElementById('fadebackgroundstyle1').style.display='block';
```

so it just block the UI. It is wroking fine in chrome and mozilla but not working in IE 8.
In my application I am using JSF 1.2.
help me out....thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a valid !DOCTYPE. Looks like IE8 needs it for the display property.

You can see the browser support for this property here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp